# How do I prevent org.eclipse.m2e lifecycle-mapping in my maven pom file?

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, maven-enforcer-plugin

I have a maven project and we usually edit it with Eclipse. Some developers keep adding information about the org.eclipse.m2e lifecycle-mapping plugin to the pluginManagement section of my nice-and-clean pom.xml. I'd rather it was added to the eclipse workspace instead.

```
 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            ...
```

I'd like to prevent that and talking to is an option, but I'd much rather combine it with automatic enforcement.

I use the "maven-enforcer-plugin" for several other checks and it looks like the obvious place to go.

I've tried the "banned plugins" rule, but that one only reacts to the build->plugins section, not the builds->pluginManagement->plugins

I also tried the "evaluate beanshell", but was unable to figure out how to reach the correct section in the pom through properties

I'd rather not write a custom rule, if it's already supported by the existing rules.

Do any of you know how to do this?

Comment: One of the reasons for me to use Maven (or automation in general) is to reduce the amount of clicking around that individuals have to do in order to get things done. (Not just for being lazy, but for getting things works consistently between developers.) As such I see the `lifecycle-mapping`s as a great service to developers!